# If {${U_i}$}$_{i\in I}$ is a countable collection of open sets, must $\cap_{i\in I}U_i$ be open? Provide proof or counterexample.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Similarly, if {$A_i$}$_{i\in I}$ is an infinite collection of closed sets, must $\cap_{i\in I}A_i$ be closed?

For the first question, I know if $\cap_{i\in I}U_i=\emptyset$ then it is true that it is open. But, if $\cap_{i\in I}U_i\neq\emptyset$ then I can see intuitively why it could still be true. By assumption, we have that all the sets {${U_i}$}$_{i\in I}$ are open so, the intersections between the sets is an area where it must be open as well since every open ball is open? Sorry, this is my first time dealing with the topology of $\Bbb R^n$ and I'm thinking about this in kind of a Venn diagram way.

For the second one, I don't really know what to do because I can't figure out what difference of the collection being infinite would mean.

Comment: You might want to look up the definition of a topology!

Comment: No a topology requires a *finite* intersection of basis elements to live in the set. But a countable union must be in the topology.

Answer (score 1):

$$\bigcap_{n \geq 1} \left(-\frac1n, \frac 1n\right)$$

For your other question, simply consider the complements of the above collection.

Answer (score 0):

The singleton
$$
\{0\}=\bigcap_{n \ge 1}\left(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$
is not open (in the usual topology).